# Use of "results" in "Substituting for the numbers results in equation A" correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have the following sentence:

> From Equation 1, x=1 and y=2. Since z=x+y, substituting for the numbers results in z=3.

I want to just check the usage of "results" is correct. My logic is that substituting for the numbers is a singular "act", as in the act of substituting for the numbers results in equation A.

Am I correct?

MS word has failed to enlighten me, accepting both versions without highlighting :)

In addition, the following doesn't sound right:

> The static nonlinearity was modelled by firstly simple polynomial and then dual-polynomial functions, the latter of which reduces the number of parameters required and the accuracy of the model.

At first glance, I should probably change `reduces` to `reduce`, as the functions are plural. But something is telling me the `latter of which' is needlessly complicated, so I attempt to write it as:

> The static nonlinearity was modelled by firstly simple polynomial and then dual-polynomial functions, with the latter reducing the number of parameters required and the accuracy of the model.

Please advise on both the validity of the change.

EDIT:
Altered original example and added 2nd part

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In this case, *substituting* is a [gerund.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gerund) And as such it takes the singular verb *results*.

Comment: The answer is "Yes, it's fine", but I do wonder 'substituting *what* for the numbers?'

Comment: @TimLymington that's clear from context in the previous clauses I haven't included here. Hence I've apended "...,"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If there is context which sheds light on the question or makes it more interesting, please always include it in the question. You can add it now by editing the question. Also add the results of your own research efforts, such as dictionaries or grammars you consulted. Thanks.

Comment: I find the juxtaposition of two nouns (“numbers results”) awkward, and join @Tim and MετάEd in wondering what context could make this make sense.

Comment: "results" is not a noun. I take this sentence to mean: From Equation 1, x=1 and y=2. Since z=x+y, substituting with the numbers produces z=3.

Comment: @Mynamite Results is not a noun, but a verb. I think you misread it, as the end is "results in", a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence would flow better as

> ... substitution results in z=3."

but "results" is, indeed, correct.

For your second example, unless you're referring to "firstly simple" polynomials, that part should read

> "... modeled firstly by simple polynomials..."

Second, either hyphenate both types of polynomials or neither. The rest of your change is valid.